# Transactional Emails not sending

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron, email-templates, transactional-mail

I am having an issue with transactional emails on Magento 1.9. Order confirmation emails are not sending. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you set up cron yet? Make triple sure your path is correct. Here's at least one StackOverflow answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748272/magento-1-9-1-cron-not-running. Also you could run a simple task through crontab itself to make sure it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your outgoing mail settings are correct and you can send email?
https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-set-up-outgoing-smtp-email-for-magento.html

I know on Magento 2 I had to setup 'sendmail' on my Linux server to send emails through Magento. I don't remember if I had to do that for 1.9.

Another recommendation is to check your Linux and Magento log files at:

```
/var/log/
/var/www/html/var/log/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons this could occur. Without further information would not be able to troubleshoot properly.

First thing I like to do is check table 'cron_schedule' in the database. Check to see if this is populating and also if it runs 'core_email_queue_send_all' is scheduled and executes without error. If there is an error it will be provided in 'messages' column.

If the row is there and it does execute, then it means generally it is the mail server, but not always. Check core_email_queue table to see if it is populated with the emails that are supposed to be sent.

Please provide the answers to above and can go from there.

I have also created an n98-magerun module to send transactional emails from command line to any email address specified to help with troubleshooting transactional email issues. It gets monotonous to have to send via admin all the time while troubleshooting.

https://github.com/djfordz/magerun-addons